# How to merge results of an Union All in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, union-all

Consider i have 2 queries with the below result set...First result set is for students, so all the columns pertaining to instructors are null.. The second result set is pertaining to instructors and column related to students are null and both of them share few common columns..
Student:

```
 uid f_name m_name l_name class school Section Dept. Branch Title
 1   abc    c     dey   2     NYU    1   null    null     null
 2   cde    d     rey   3     CU     2   null    null     null
 3   xyz    r     mey   4     LSU    3   null    null     null
```

Teacher:

```
uid f_name m_name l_name class school Section Dept. Branch Title
4    wss    c     tey  null    null     null   Science  Biology  Asso.Prof
2    cde    d     rey  null    null     null   Arts     Music    Asso.Prof
5    rrr    r     jey  null    null     null   Science  Chemistry Prof
```

If you look in the above result set, UID 2 is common in both the result set, that basically means a professor can also be a student at the same time... Now i want to join/merge these two queries into a common resultset say 'Users' who are basically the teachers and students.

The result set of 'Users' should be unique with respect to UID. If i use union all, there will be duplicates on UID 2. I need  a query which can merge the columns for a single row... The result set should be:

```
1   abc    c     dey   2     NYU    1   null    null     null
2   cde    d     rey   3     CU     2   Arts    Music     Asso.Prof
3   xyz    r     mey   4     LSU    3   null    null     null
4   wss    c     tey  null    null     null   Science  Biology  Asso.Prof
5   rrr    r     jey  null    null     null   Science  Chemistry Prof
```

Note 2 above, it has both student and professor details in one row...

How can i achieve this in Oracle ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think that UNION is not the right approach here. What is the source of your 2 queries?? Please show the SQL.  Either there's one source  table  storing "people" with both students and teachers, or you have 2 different tables for them and it is bad design. There are 2 different approaches for the 2 scenarios,  I just don't know which one to pick because you haven't provided enough information

Comment: @ThomasG The 2 queries are complex join queries, but both use a common source say 'Persons'. But there is no way to distinguish if a person is a student or a teacher in that table, it just stores person and his details. It might be a bad design, but its already placed and used in like million other places...Say there are 2 other tables, students and teachers...So inner joining student, persons and some other student related table gives me all student details..Similarly inner joining teachers table with persons, other person data tables gives me all the teacher details..

Comment: Look at full outer join Student with Teacher on uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in Comments, this is a poor design (or perhaps a poor solution using a good design). If the base tables are "person" (containing only information that is of the same kind for students and instructors, such as UID, name, date of birth, email etc.), "student" (with UID as foreign key, and showing only characteristics specific to students) and "teacher" (same for teachers or instructors), then the design is fine, and your desired final output can be obtained directly from these base tables, not from the results of other queries you have written. jva shows something along these lines in his/her answer.

If you really have to put up with it, the way to use your existing queries is to use `union all` - but then you must `group by uid`, and for each column you must select `max(...)` - for example `max(f_name)` and `max(school)`. Use column aliases in the SELECT clause, for example `select ....  , max(school) as school, ...`

Or, slightly more efficiently (but with some risks), `group by id, f_name, m_name, l_name` and select `max(...)` only for the remaining columns. The risk is that in one place the `m_name` is `N` and in the other it is null; that is, your data is internally inconsistent. (If it all comes from one base table, "person", then this risk shouldn't exist.)

Comment: I changed my solution such that in query one i am joining Students with persons and also making sure that the UID returned is not in Instructor related table. So, this way i am making sure that (student only excluding teacher) Union ( teacher only) . Seems to work fine. Thanks for the input

Comment: The `union all` and `group by` approach may be faster than what you are describing. Try it both ways and decide. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This would be the general approach:

```
SELECT persons.id
      ,nvl(<some_student_field>, <same_teacher_field) as some_common_field
      ,... 
FROM persons 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN students on (person.id = students.person_id)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers on (person.id = teachers.person_id)
WHERE <mandatory_field_for_students> IS NOT NULL
   OR <mandatory_field_for_teachers> IS NOT NULL
```